# How I can declare any parameter in any order and Set it correctly according to its type in PHP, polymorphism?

Tags: php, polymorphism

I'm investigating methods of obtaining multiple parameters in the methods or functions PHP, something like:

```
public function fx($param1, $param2, $param3, ....)
{
// do something...
}
```

Right now we can make these types of statements in PHP

```
public function foo($param1, $param2) {} // parameters 1 and 2 are mandatory
public function foo($param1, $param2 = "", $param3 = "") {} //param1 is mandatory, param two and tree are optional but if i can need set $param3 we need set $param2...
```

Now my question is how can I have multiple parameters and can declare in diferent and that order does not matter in the statement. Something like this:

```
public function foo($param1, $param2 = "", $param3 = "") 
{ 
   echo "Result from $param1 is :" . $param2 / $param3; 
}
foo("first", $param2 = 0 , $param3 = 1); // "Result from foo is : 0"
foo("second", $param3 = 1, $param2 = 0); // "Result from bar is : 0"
```

I can do something like this, getting all arguments and then process with `func_get_args`. There is something like what I want , or at least implement a method to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want named parameters that you can set in any order you like, you can use associative arrays to do that:

```
<?php
function foo($params)
{
    $defaults = array(
        'param2' => 2,
        'param3' => 3
    );
    $params = array_merge($defaults, $params);

    if (!isset($params['param1'])) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Missing param1');
    }

    echo "Result from $param1 is :" . $params['param2'] / $params['param3']; 
}

foo(array(
    'param1' => 1,
    'param2' => 10,
    'param3' => 2
));
```

Comment: OK, that is like jquery style or something, i have already implement that. its very useful. thanks